# Jenkins Xcode build works but at the end have a DVTSigningCertificateSource error

Tags: xcode, jenkins, code-signing, keychain, xcodebuild

We have a Jenkins job which is producing a framework and uploading it after every commit.

The Jenkins job was has been working for a long a time , around a year, but now we are getting failures 5/6 times at the very end of the job regarding "`DVTSigningCertificateSource`". This means that I can run the **exact same job**. It will fail most times but pass sometimes.

The exact error we are seeing in the log is:

```
[MT] DVTSigningCertificateSource: Unknown keychain event: 11
```

Our build script is something like this (Omitting irrelevant parts):

```
# create slice for iphone
xcodebuild -scheme myscheme -sdk iphoneos
# create slice for simulator
xcodebuild -scheme myscheme -sdk iphonesimulator
# create universal binary
mkdir build/Universal
cp -rf build/Release-iphoneos/MyFramework.framework build/Universal
lipo -create build/Release-iphonesimulator/Myframework.framework/MyFramework build/Release-iphoneos/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework -output build/Universal/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
```